# Instert an icon inside of an EnumProperty ? is it possible? (addon UI)

Tags: python, scripting

i tried to insert some icon in an enumproperty

```
test_context: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name = 'Context',
    description = '',
    items = [
        ('GENERAL', 'General', '', icon='BLENDER'),
        ('FILEPATHS', 'File Paths', '', icon='KEYINGSET')],
    default = 'GENERAL')
```

this is obviously not working and i didnt saw any example out there, nothing in the documentation either. 
i saw this question but it didnt help
[How to add custom icon to EnumProperty in add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73876/how-to-add-custom-icon-to-enumproperty-in-add-on)

does someone here know how to do this ? is this even possible ?

original

```
test_context: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name = 'Context',
    description = '',
    items = [
        ('GENERAL', 'General', '', icon='BLENDER'),
        ('FILEPATHS', 'File Paths', '', icon='KEYINGSET')],
    default = 'GENERAL')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
test_context: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name = 'Context',
    description = '',
    items = [
        ('GENERAL', 'General', '', 'BLENDER',1),
        ('FILEPATHS', 'File Paths', '', 'KEYINGSET',2)],
    default = 'GENERAL')
```